# How to export csv object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to figure out if there is any way I can download a csv file onClick of the EXPORT button on my webpage using react.

Here's what I have under component right now -

```
<div>
    <Button variant="contained" 
        size="small" 
        onClick={this.handleExport}>
        <SaveIcon label="Export" />
        Export
    </Button>
</div>
```

where handleExport generates a csv file using JSON data from backend.

I have tried to use react-csv, react-csv-downloader packages but none of them work for me.

Is there any way I can download the csv file onClick? Sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: why the language tag spam?

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have this logic implemented. Code is very self explanatory.

```js
    export function exportCSVFile(headers, items, fileTitle) {
      if (headers) {
        items.unshift(headers)
      }
    
      // Convert Object to JSON
      var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items)
    
      var csv = convertToCSV(jsonObject)
    
      var exportedFilename = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv'
    
      var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' })
      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilename)
      } else {
        var link = document.createElement('a')
        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
          // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          link.setAttribute('href', url)
          link.setAttribute('download', exportedFilename)
          link.style.visibility = 'hidden'
          document.body.appendChild(link)
          link.click()
          document.body.removeChild(link)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ok but where the "convertToCSV" method comes from? it's a your custom function, an imported module... how can it be reproduced?

Comment: `convertToCSV` is just a function that converts json object to comma separated I guess. But indeed the answer is careless...